# Mathematical expression to show 10 numbers from an array each time you click the button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, logic

I have a 1 button when i click the button it should show 10 numbers from an array, I have an array which contains numbers from 1 to 35 for ex: const items = [1,2,3....35] i want to show only 10 numbers each time from the array when i click the button, for example
click button
1-10
click button
11-20,
click button
21-30,
click button
31-35
so i dont know how to use a mathematical logic for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  If so, please post your code and explain why the outcome was not what you expected.

Comment: There's several ways to do this. The naive solution would be to generate 10 random numbers between 0 and 34 to use as indexes for the array of 35 numbers and then just map that. But i'm sure there's more efficient ways I'm not thinking of immediately. If the numbers shown should not be random, but will always be button 1 showing 1-10, then I heave no idea why you need an array of 35 numbers to begin with.

Comment: @Shilly - `1st: 1-10 click button 2nd: 11-20, click button 3rd: 21-30` <- they don't want random numbers.

Comment: @Archer- i am not able to generate logic i got struck const step = Math.ceil((items.length - 10) / 10)
let n = 1
for (let i = n; i < (n * 10) - 1; i++) 
{
  
  
}

Comment: Hence I stated that I do not understand the use of 10 numbers from a  35 number array. The solutions is then just like array.slice( x, x + 10 ); with x being the index of the button. But the result is fixed, so why an array?

Comment: i dont know what condition to use for i < (condition)

Comment: Please update the question to include your code so far.

Comment: Mathematical logic for paging? offset * numberOfRows....

Comment: @rogerking What happens on the 5th click? Will you start over with 1-10 or do you expect an empty array?

Comment: @Shilly at 5th click it should not do anything because all the values are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35];

let count_clicks = 0;

document.querySelector( 'button' ).addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  const next = numbers.slice( count_clicks * 10, count_clicks * 10 + 10 );
  if ( next.length ) {
    console.log( next );
    count_clicks += 1;
  }
});
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

By slicing first and then checking length, you can add extra numbers to the array. So once you have an 40th number, you'll be able to click a 5th time.

Comment: It's just 1 button.

Comment: really? Does the numbes array have to stay the same? Or can it dispppear? What happens at the 5th click?

Comment: Ask the OP, under the question.  The question is unclear so I don't think an answer right now will help anyone.

Comment: Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextTenElements(numberArray, currentClickCount){
    var startIndex = currentClickCount * 10;

    //+11 because param is exclusive
    return numberArray.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 11);
}
```